# Authentication against database, Active Directory and Radius in Symfony?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, active-directory, radius

I'm using Symfony2 as framework but up until now I was using my own code for authentication and authorization. I decided to give Symfony's security system a try and after following the tutorial on its website I'm now able to login using my database.

But... I need to authenticate against a Radius server and an Active Directory if the authentication against the database fails.

Can these multiple methods of authentication be combined? how would I do that?

Comment: look at https://github.com/ztec/ZtecSecurityActiveDirectoryBundle and http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create my own user authentication provider. You only need to extend UserAuthenticationProvider and do your own thing in the checkAuthentication method

Comment: Do you have some sample code you can point me at? I'm in the same boat as you. I'm having trouble figuring out where to wire-in my auth provider.